# Alternative to 3 Synchronized CStringList's

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have 3 CStringList’s:

- parameterNameList
- parameterValueList
- parameterID

The lists are synchronized, which means that the value (found in parameterValueList) of a named parameter (found in parameterNameList) are located in the same position (index\POSITION) in their respective StringLists. The same goes for parameterID.

Im looking for an alternative to having 3 StringLists and thought about using a CMap with parameterID as key and create a class to hold name and value.

**Question:** What would be the best solution for replacing my 3 CStringList objects ?

**Additional:** The collection\list\map must be fairly easy to sort and be serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a std::map

```
struct DATA
{
    CString strName;
    CSTring strValue;    
};

typedef std::map<CString,DATA> MYDATAMAP;
```

It is sorted and easy to iterate. Createing a serializer is easy too.

Comment: isn't std::pair better than the struct in this case?

Comment: Per would be suitable, but better? From my point of view such DATA blocks are more redable and understandable than using pair. But yes. std::pair will work too!